# ASP.NET MVC - View is rendering values that do not exist?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this:

```
model.PasswordField = null;
return View("MainLogin", model);
```

My model contains `LoginField` and `PasswordField`. I leave `LoginField` untouched, but I erase `PasswordField`. Now, when `MainLogin` view is rendered, the field password has a value from my previous request! Why?

Update: Added my view code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PasswordField, new { placeholder = "Password" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PasswordField)
            </div>
```

Comment: please include your view in post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the value in the Model but the HtmlHelper methods check the ModelState first to display the value, on postback. This is by design. To display the modified value, you need to clear the ModelState using,

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

in the load of your form you can create a function clean() where you put an initialization of field you want to be empty 
for example

```
clean()
{

textlabel.setvalue="enter text ";
field1.empty();

passwordField.empty();
}
```

Comment: then at the start of your form the function initialize part of your field

Comment: Well that's cool, thanks for that. But anyways, I am looking for the answer why is that value in my view, it shouldn't!

Comment: perhaps they keep the value like a default value of the password field
look at the value at the property field

Comment: @Benius, while I wouldn't rule it out, this seems like blind guessing.

Comment: @Benius: It is highly unlikely, since i am testing this now with variety of values, and my browser would ask me if i want to keep those as default.

Comment: did you have a cookies system?